# EnumerateFiles vs EnumerateDirectories searchPattern

Tags: c#, io

I've come across one thing. 
There is code:

```
 var searchPattern = @"??????";
 var path = "C:\Users\MyUser\Folder";

 IEnumerable<string> file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern);
 IEnumerable<string> dir = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, searchPattern);
```

and lets say following directories and files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
a
b
```

According to [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) there "?" char should represent zero or one character in that position. Therefore I expect *dir* containing `a` and `b` and file should be `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

However my `file` variable contains only empty collection. 
Why is that?

Comment: Put `"?.*"` for file (one letter name, any extension)

Comment: I guess it's not supposed to work used like that. Why do you need this ?

Comment: I'm trying to create my own `EnumerateFiles` method (don't ask why:)) but this is some behavior i did not expect.

Comment: It is not accurate, not zero.  [This is better](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490639.aspx).  The way wildcards work goes back a long, long time, back to DEC operating systems that ran on machines with very little horsepower.  You tend to need `"*.*"` and filter yourself with, say, Regexp

Comment: Also beware of legacy short name support on file systems, still turned on today by default.  A pattern like `"*.doc"` does not just find .doc files but also, say, "foo.docx" and "foo.document".  More reasons to use `"*.*"` and filter yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation!